# How to log overall class used by two classes

Tags: java, logging, log4j

There is a class A and a class B. They both use class C with help of composition. Class A and class B need to generate own in different files, for example: class A generates log to file "log_A.log" and class B - in "log_B.log".

My question is - how to write log of a class C accoerding to a class that invokes class C's method? I mean: if method of a class C was invoked from class A, log of a class C should be generated to to log file for class A - "log_A.log". If method of a class C was invoked from class B, log of class C should be generated to file "log_B.log".  And one thing else - logging level for class C should be the same as for logger of a class A or B.

For example, class A:

```
//loggerA - it's logger that writes to file "log_A.log"
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("loggerA");
public void method(){
    log.debug("Write to log of class A");
    C c = new C();
    c.method(); //activity in class C should be written to "log_A.log" as well
}
```

In class B:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("loggerB");
public void method(){
    log.debug("Write to log of class B");
    C c = new C();
    c.method(); //activity in class C should be written to "log_B.log" as well
}
```

In class C:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(???);
public void method(){

    log.debug("Any log message");

}
```

P.S. I use log4j 1.2.16

I can try to do the following:
In class C:

```
public void method(String logger){
    final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(logger); //Use the logger of calling class
    log.debug("Any log message");

}
```

But I think it's dirty decision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a constructor of class C which takes logger as parameter.
Now while instantiating C in any other class, pass that class's logger to C.
Something like -

```
class C {
    public C(Logger log) {
        this.log = log;
    }
}
```

and then in A or B, use it like -

```
C c = new C(this.log);
c.method();
```

Comment: You can remove static keywork from C's logger. It doesn't make sense as we need different logger per instance. Infact keeping it static will create problems as other instance's logger will be modified.